# VB.Net Call function from another class in combination with inheritance

Tags: vb.net, function, inheritance, methods, mvvm

I'm writing a program where I have to call a function from another class. I know you can call functions from another class using "public shared function" and this works. But when I do this the "Inherits" statement doesn't work anymore. In the function itselfs I fill parameters with variables from another class. Thats why I use the inherits statements.

I am relatively new to programming and this is my first post.

**This is the function. It inherits name, pass and role from another class**

```
Public Class AccountaddModel
Inherits AccountaddViewModel

Public Function addUser()
    Dim url As String = "https://myPrivateWebsite" + "&name=" + (username) + "&pass=" + (pass) + "&role=" + (role)
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim result As String = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
End Function
End Class
```

**These are the variables the function needs:**

```
Public Class AccountaddViewModel
Inherits AccountaddView
Public username As String = txtUsernameAdd.Text
Public pass As String = txtPasswordAdd.Password
Public role As String = txtProjectrolAdd.Text
End Class
```

**I try to call the function from the 3rd class here and this does not work**

```
Public Class AccountaddView
Public Sub btnAccountAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAccountAdd.Click
            AccountaddModel.addUser()
```

Error message: *reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference*

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

It appears that the problem for which most of the information in the question was provided is not the actual problem that needs to be solved. If the issue is that you cannot call a `Shared` method on a derived class then that's just the way it is and it makes perfect sense if you understand how inheritance works.

The main point of inheritance is polymorphism, which is a foundation of OOP. The idea is that you can declare a method in a base class, inherit that class and then override the method in the derived class to provide a different implementation. You can then call that method on a reference of either the base class or the derived class and it will be the derived implementation that is invoked.

That's the case for instance members but not `Shared` members. You cannot override a `Shared` method in a derived class so there's no point to inheriting a `Shared` method at all, so you don't. A `Shared` method remains a member of the base class and you call it on the base class. There's no polymorphism because there are no objects or object references so being able to call the method on a derived class serves no purpose, so it can't be done.

There is no problem to solve. If you want to call a `Shared` method then you call it on a type, not an instance of that type, and you call it on the type it was declared in, not a type that inherits that.

Original:

You have to create an object of that type, then call the method on the object. Look at how you're calling methods in your first code snippet. Here:

```vb
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
```

you are calling the `Shared` method `Create`, so you call it on the class itself. Everywhere else:

```vb
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim result As String = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
```

you're calling instance methods so you have to have an instance to call them on, i.e. you have create an object first, then call the method on the object. If you expect to call that instance method `addUser` then you need an instance of the `AccountaddModel` class to call it on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont understand how that can solve my overlying problem. Why can't I call a Shared function in a class that uses the inheritance method? And how do I solve this?

Comment: @JustinThns, if that's the question you wanted answered then why isn't there any code in your question to demonstrate that? The code you did post demonstrates a problem but, apparently, that's not the problem you want solved. That's not going to confuse anyone at all.

Comment: @JustinThns, I have edited to my answer to address what appears to be the question you actually wanted answered.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to make that function static / Shared

```vb
Public Class AccountaddModel
    Inherits AccountaddViewModel

    Public Shared Function addUser()
        Dim url As String = "https://myPrivateWebsite" + "&name=" + (username) + "&pass=" + (pass) + "&role=" + (role)
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim result As String = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
    End Function
End Class
```

but then you have the problem where it accesses non-shared members from its base class, so you will want to make those shared too

```vb
Public Class AccountaddViewModel
    Inherits AccountaddView

    Public Shared username As String = txtUsernameAdd.Text
    Public Shared pass As String = txtPasswordAdd.Password
    Public Shared role As String = txtProjectrolAdd.Text
End Class
```

and you have the same issue there, where those textboxes aren't shared, and since you can't make them shared, you are at the end of the experiment.

Instead you need an instance of `AccountaddModel`, like this

```vb
Dim model = New AccountaddModel()
```

but this is very rudimentary and judging by the context of your code, you won't be making the instance like this, rather in the manner that the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72290034/832052) does it, so follow that.

Comment: Tanks a lot. I managed to call my function (model) from the view! Now I have the problem that it does not inherit the textbox values the user enters. I posted this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305157/vb-net-function-does-not-inherit-textbox-values-from-another-class